# How to recover files from SD card on HTC Merge?

Tags: htc-desire, sd-card, hardware, images, factory-reset

So today somehow my phone completely reset itself. I went into my local wireless office and they helped me a bit. My phone has lost all of it's contacts and apps (no biggie) but the employee told me that pictures and video would still be on the SD card. I can't find my pictures *anywhere* on my phone. Would they still be on the SD card? If so, how can I get to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If there are video or photo on sdcard you see it to plugin your sdcard on device to can read an sdcard. On htc there are no encrypt of data on sdcard by default

Answer (score 1):

try using a file explorer like this [Astro File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tZXRhZ28uYXN0cm8iXQ..) on your phone and you will be able to see all files, photos , vids stored in your memory either phone memory or SD card